# How to store joda.money in mysql

Tags: hibernate, joda-money

I have a class which has attribute of datatype joda.money. 
How can I map this attribute into mysql.

my class is:

> @Table(name="products") public class Product(){ @Column(name="name")
>   String name; @Column(name="money") Money money; }

I am using spring hibernate

Can anyone tell how to store this model into mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have more choices here.

1. You can make two fields representing Joda's `Money`. `BigDecimal` for amount and `String` for currency. Then create transient synthetic field `Money` and create it in getter (see example below).
2. You can implement your own `UserType` and provide serialization/deserialization by your own. See javadoc [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) and documenatation [Custom types using org.hibernate.usertype.UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#types-custom-ut). Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/ddd-cqrs-base-project/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/nthdimenzion/ddd/domain/sharedkernel/MoneyType.java) implementation of `CompositeUserType`.
3. You can include [Jadira](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/) Usertypes project which provides Joda `Money` support for Hibernate (I've never tryied anyway)

   ```
   @Entity @Table(name = "products")
   public class Product {
       @Basic @Column
       private BigDecimal amount;

       @Basic @Column
       private String currency;

       private transient Money money;

           public Money getMoney() {
               if (money == null) {
                   money = Money.of(CurrencyUnit.of(currency), amount);
               }

               return money;
           }
   }
   ```