# How to store currency in a single field per table for Joda Money & Jadira User Type

Tags: hibernate, joda-money

I'm using JodaMoney library and the Jadira User types to store monetary values. I want to be able to store a single currency per table, instead of needing so many fields.

Is there a way to map the currencies to the same field? This doesn't work because it complains I can't mix insertable and updatable.

```
    @Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "currency"), @Column(name = "productsAmount")})
   @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency")
    private Money totalProducts;

    @Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "currency", insertable = false, updatable= false), @Column(name = "orderTotalAmount") })
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency")
    private Money orderTotalAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with `org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.moneta.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency` as well and get the same error as you do:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed
```

A quick and dirty solution is already proposed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382176/1289270), and more specifically the first point: Instead of going with Jadira, he suggests using transient fields.

I myself don't feel really comfortable with this approach as a long term solution, so I'll look into implementing a `UserType`, as suggested at the second point of the same SO answer.

If I ever have a working implementation I'll post it back here.

ps: There's also [@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter solution(name = "currencyCode", value = "USD")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25777717/1289270) solution which I guess doesn't fit your use-case since it's hardcoding the currency in the annotation.